# what the fastest way to draw pixels buffer in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics

Now I  am using adopted code from  [Dummy’s guide to drawing raw images in Java 2D](http://tech.puredanger.com/2007/10/12/images-java2d/)
And I gets 240 FPS, for 800x600 window, on  Debian i386  with Oracle JVM, Nvidia 8600 GTS, Intel Core 2Duo 2.6 GHz.

Is exist faster way? My code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestFillRasterRate
{
    static class MyFrame extends JFrame
    {
      long framesDrawed;
      int col=0;

      int w, h;
      int[] raster;
      ColorModel cm;
      DataBuffer buffer;
      SampleModel sm;
      WritableRaster wrRaster;
      BufferedImage backBuffer;

      //@Override public void paint(Graphics g)
      public void draw(Graphics g)
      {
        // reinitialize all if resized
        if( w!=getWidth() || h!=getHeight() )
        {
            w = getWidth();
            h = getHeight();

            raster = new int[w*h];

            cm = new DirectColorModel(24, 255, 255<<8, 255<<16);
            buffer = new DataBufferInt(raster, raster.length);
            sm = cm.createCompatibleSampleModel(w,h);
            wrRaster = Raster.createWritableRaster(sm, buffer, null);
            backBuffer = new BufferedImage(cm, wrRaster, false, null);
        }

        // produce raster
        for(int ptr=0, x=0; x<w; x++)
            for(int y=0; y<h; y++)
              raster[ptr++] = col++;

        // draw raster
        g.drawImage(backBuffer,  0,0, null);
        ++framesDrawed;

        /**
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {   @Override   public void run()
            {     repaint();
            }
        });/**/
      }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      final MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();

        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // draw FPS in title
        new Timer(1000, new ActionListener()
        {   @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {   frame.setTitle(Long.toString(frame.framesDrawed));
                frame.framesDrawed = 0;
            }
        }).start();

      /**/
      frame.createBufferStrategy(1);
      BufferStrategy bs = frame.getBufferStrategy();
      Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
      for(;;)
        frame.draw(g);
      /**/
    }
}
```

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Whats the question here? *Is exist faster way?* - Is 240 fps not fast enough? What does the screenshot have to do with your question? It looks like somethings wrong with it...

Comment: nothing wrong, it is screen filled with incrementing int_argb, for test.

Comment: A related [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/raster) is seen here.

Answer (score 2):

A way to get more FPS would probably be to use a `BufferStrategy`. Instead of using the `Graphics` passed my the `paint()` method, you would have to create them externally with e.g.`jFrame.createBufferStrategy(/*number of buffers*/)` and `BufferStrategy bufferStrategy = jFrame.getBufferStrategy()`.
If you then want to access the `Graphics`, you use `Graphics g = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics()` and then draw your Image as usually. I am not sure if this will really improve your FPS at such a simple example, but when doing more complicated draws, it surely will.

EDIT: It's pretty useless to create a `BufferStrategy` with only 1 backbuffer, since it would just continue drawing directly to the screen. The buffersize should be 2-5 depending on how much vram your graphics card can handle.